# Summarize data from one dataframe to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapreduce

I would like to help you for what follows.

In my work I have two DataFrames. The first, called `df_card_features`, has card features and the card_id column has the unique ID of each card. The second, called `df_cart_historic`, has card data from the first dataframe; in this second dataframe, the card_id column has no unique values, but is the same as the card_id column of the first dataframe.

As a solution I thought about creating a dictionary and then include the columns in the dataframe, but this proposal seems to me very costly in terms of performance, because the csv file of history has about 5 GB.

```
# card features:
card_id = ['card_a', 'card_b', 'card_c', 'card_d', 'card_e']
date_activation = ['2019-02-01', '2019-05-02', '2018-01-20', '2015-07-23', '2013-07-23']
feature_1_1 = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
feature_1_2 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
df_card_features = pd.DataFrame()
df_card_features['card_id'] = card_id
df_card_features['date_activation'] = date_activation
df_card_features['feature_1_1'] = feature_1_1
df_card_features['feature_1_2'] = feature_1_2;
df_card_features.head()


# card historic
card_id = ['card_a', 'card_b', 'card_c', 'card_d', 'card_e', 'card_a', 'card_b', 'card_c', 'card_d', 'card_e', 'card_a', 'card_b', 'card_c', 'card_d', 'card_e']
denied_purchase = ['N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'Y']
purchase_date = ['2019-02-01', '2019-02-01', '2019-02-01', '2019-02-01', '2019-02-01', '2019-02-10', '2019-02-11', '2019-02-21', '2019-03-01', '2019-03-01', '2019-03-01', '2019-03-31', '2018-04-01', '2016-02-01', '2013-12-01']
installments = [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 8, 4, 0 ]
month_lag = [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5]
df_cart_historic = pd.DataFrame()
df_cart_historic['card_id'] = card_id
df_cart_historic['denied_purchase'] = denied_purchase
df_cart_historic['purchase_date'] = purchase_date
df_cart_historic['installments'] = installments
df_cart_historic['month_lag'] = month_lag
```

What I need is to create the following columns in the df_card_features dataframe:

1. column 'denied_purchase?' Whose value is 1 if there is at least one Y value occurrence in the denied_purchase column of the df_cart_historic dataframe or zero if there is no Y occurrence for the card_id
2. 'oldest_Date' column, whose value is the oldest date in the purchase_date column of df_cart_historic
3. 'max_installments', which is the maximum value of the installments column of df_cart_historic
4. 'max_month_lag', which is the maximum value of the month_lag column of df_cart_historic.

Comment: Hey Angelo, can you provide a sample of your data sets, and expected output? people will find it much easier to help you that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yoy need to use `groupby` on `'card_id'` column in `df_cart_historic` in order to build the new columns using only the rows where `'card_id'` has the same value.
By calling `groupby('card_id').apply(func)` you can use a custom function `func` which does the job.

Here a working example:

```
import pandas as pd

# card features:
card_id = ['card_a', 'card_b', 'card_c', 'card_d', 'card_e']
date_activation = ['2019-02-01', '2019-05-02', '2018-01-20', '2015-07-23', '2013-07-23']
feature_1_1 = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
feature_1_2 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
df_card_features = pd.DataFrame()
df_card_features['card_id'] = card_id
df_card_features['date_activation'] = pd.to_datetime(date_activation) #converting to datetime
df_card_features['feature_1_1'] = feature_1_1
df_card_features['feature_1_2'] = feature_1_2;
df_card_features.head()


# card historic
card_id = ['card_a', 'card_b', 'card_c', 'card_d', 'card_e', 'card_a', 'card_b', 'card_c', 'card_d', 'card_e', 'card_a', 'card_b', 'card_c', 'card_d', 'card_e']
denied_purchase = ['N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'Y']
purchase_date = ['2019-02-01', '2019-02-01', '2019-02-01', '2019-02-01', '2019-02-01', '2019-02-10', '2019-02-11', '2019-02-21', '2019-03-01', '2019-03-01', '2019-03-01', '2019-03-31', '2018-04-01', '2016-02-01', '2013-12-01']
installments = [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 8, 4, 0 ]
month_lag = [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5]
df_cart_historic = pd.DataFrame()
df_cart_historic['card_id'] = card_id
df_cart_historic['denied_purchase'] = denied_purchase
df_cart_historic['purchase_date'] = pd.to_datetime(purchase_date) #converting to datetime
df_cart_historic['installments'] = installments
df_cart_historic['month_lag'] = month_lag

df_card_features.set_index('card_id', inplace=True) #using card_id column as index

def getnewcols(x):
    res = pd.DataFrame()
    res['denied_purchase?'] = pd.Series(['Y' if 'Y' in x['denied_purchase'].unique() else 'N'])
    res['oldest_Date'] = x['purchase_date'].min()
    res['max_installments'] = x['installments'].max()
    res['max_month_lag'] = x['month_lag'].max()
    return res

newcols = df_cart_historic.groupby('card_id').apply(getnewcols)
newcols = newcols.reset_index().drop('level_1', axis=1).set_index('card_id')
df_card_features_final = pd.concat([df_card_features, newcols], axis=1)
```

Notice that the column with dates is parsed with `pandas.to_datetime` in order to have `datetime` objects instead of simple strings (very handful to work with dates).
`newcols` is the dataframe holding the new columns, `df_card_features_final` is the final dataframe with all the columns:

```
        date_activation  feature_1_1  feature_1_2 denied_purchase? oldest_Date  max_installments  max_month_lag
card_id                                                                                                        
card_a       2019-02-01            0            1                N  2019-02-01                 0              0
card_b       2019-05-02            1            0                Y  2019-02-01                 0              0
card_c       2018-01-20            1            0                N  2018-04-01                 8              0
card_d       2015-07-23            1            0                Y  2016-02-01                 4              0
card_e       2013-07-23            0            1                Y  2013-12-01                 5              5
```

Comment: Thank you very much Valentino. I was trying to using a dict comprehensive.

Comment: Maybe you can do that way too, but using `pandas` methods is usually faster. If you need to work with large data this solution should be efficient too.